# Mifare Ultralight C write for Arduino UNO with NFC shield from SeeedStudio?

Tags: arduino, nfc, mifare

I am currently have the `problem` with writing into `NFC Mifare Ultralight C tag` from NXP. For the Arduino with given libraries from SeeedStudio or Adafruit. They only give supported examples with Mifare classic standard with blocks/sectors, and does not support Mifare Ultralight C with pages. Do anyone can give me the hint to work with this kind of tag? I want to write the key to the tag for authentication purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to follow one of these ways:

1. You can dig into the [datasheet(s)](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN1303.pdf) of the [mifare](/questions/tagged/mifare) Ultralight tags and the NFC controller (PN532?). If you have time - that is a good way to understand the stuff.
2. Another option is to get the code examples from the [open-nfc](/questions/tagged/open-nfc) [project](http://open-nfc.org/wp/home/documentation/tags-compatibility/).

Comment: Hi, do you know whether the code example from open-nfc project can work for Arduino?

Comment: I guess not directly, but you can look up how the tags are accessed.

Comment: Hi, I dig into the library, and can read the data from the tag, but when I write, I got the problem

Comment: Do you know about Arduino with PN532 library?

Comment: Yes. Take, for instance, the NFC shield from seeedstudio: http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/NFC_Shield_V2.0

Comment: Do you know how to authenticate with 3DES? I cannot see any tutorial about that

Comment: http://www.libnfc.org/community/topic/665/mifare-ultralight-c-3des-authentication-apdus/